# Mouse pointer and keyboard Freeze when pluggin in external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, mouse, freeze, logitech-mouse

so as I say in the title I have this very big, annoying problem.

On my new PC (HP Omen 2020, i7-10750h, Nvidia RTX 2070, 16GB RAM) when I connect an external hard drive (precisely an WD My Passport Ultra, 3TB) I get occasionally mouse and keyboard freezes.

Practically, the system becomes unusable. The mouse and keyboards works, they even show in device manager, but from time to time (too often) they "freezes": mouse pointer freeze, and it won't respond to my input, and keyboard too, if I type something it will not respond.

First I thought this was a behaviour due to bad drivers, or something related to my new PC, the fact that it has USB 3.1 ports.

But then I've noticed that this fact happens only when I connect my WD Hard Disk (which is USB 3.0) to my pc.

I've tried some stuff online, suggesting to update drivers, change some windows settings, but with no success.
My guess is that the hard disk and the mouse-keyboard does interfere with each other in some ways. I guess that it's a software problem, at driver levels maybe, not a physical one.

When the mouse doesn't respond, I've tried to use the touchpad on the notebook, and it does work. So it's not a windows freeze, it's just the device (mouse-keyboard-receiver) that doesn't respond.

The mouse and keyboard are from Logitech, bot connected with the Unifiying receiver (a wireless receiver they provide for the mouse and the keyboard). Model: MX Anywhere 2S for the mouse, K360 for the keyboard.

Please, help me solve this problem, monday I start taking my engineering class lessons from MS Teams, and I need my pc up and running and well responsive (I need to access data from the hard disk while I take classes).

PS: I've seen that there are some other questions like this in the forum, but none of them seems to provide a solution to the problem. I would also change the external hard drive in the future, but I need to know that the problem with this one won't show with another hard drive, or other devices.
I've already sent this very same post to Microsoft community, I really need help with this thing otherwise it will be a problem following my online classes.

Thank you if you will try to help me

EDIT:
On the notebook in question I have 4 USB 3.1 Ports, with two ports on each side, and a single Type-C Thunderbolt port (I'm not counting that one cause both the hard disk and the logitech receiver are USB 3.0 type A connectors).

I've already tried switching USB port, connecting the WD Hard Disk to another port, doing the same on the logitech receiver, and I've even tried putting them one on the left side and the other to the right side, to minimize "interference" as someone suggested. But nothing, I still got this problem, which seems driver-related.
Hope this will give more info

Comment: How many USB port do you have & how are they distributed? Test different configurations. If you have ports to each side, put the Drive on the other side, away from everything else. If the drive has an external PSU, connect it first.

Comment: Someone (I guess the automatic system) has tagged my question as incomplete (lacking of details). Now I've updated it.. What can I do to make it active again?

However like I've written in the post I've already done everything you've suggested, with no success.

Comment: Your revision will go through a review process by other high-reputation users. I see you've got 4 reopen votes already from this process - only one more to go ;)

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because your keyboard & mouse are logitec? Because honestly I haven't ever in all the years and all the systems I've used seen logitec peripherals that didn't have stability issues at least some of the time. Don't sue me, please, broke anyway ...